# Visual Studio Code column mode paste

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can select a column in MS Visual Studio code with shift-alt and drag, but how do I paste a column? I can't find that anywhere. The column mode options on the keyboard cheat shortcuts list do not list this.

Comment: Yep, this will be a great feature, cant find it either

Answer (score 14):

Column copied using <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> can be pasted as a column if you start cursor at exactly same number of lines as that of number of lines in your copied column contents.
**Example:**
 Say the 2nd column in the following text is copied. (it has 2 rows)

```
foo foo1
bar bar1
```

Now, using same <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>, place cursors on two different rows. Say after 2 and 3 in below text:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Once you paste, the column will be pasted properly.

```
1
2foo1
3bar1
4
```

Comment: Can paste a "blob" (previously copied rectangular area) without causing any of the text on the right to shift?

Answer (score 4):

The lines you copied in the column must be exactly the same number as the places you selected to insert. Or the column will be inserted in every place you selected.

Comment: Life-saver comment, I would never have guessed that!
I guess that warrants opening a GitHub issue… or using this plugin:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnguo.columnpaste

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding Bharat's reply, that's not very useful, is it? That means if I want to compare 2 columns side by side and one column doesn't have as many rows as the other then I can't do it.  Or I can do it only if I first count the number of rows in the shorter column so that I can highlight that many rows and then paste into that selection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1088750)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).